# Pandas iloc complex slice every nth row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice

I have a dataframe with a periodicity in the rows of 14 i.e. there are 14 lines of data per record (means, sdev etc.) and I want to extract the 2nd, 4th, 7th and 9th line, repeatedly for every record (14 lines). My code is:

`Mean_df = df.iloc[[1,3,6,8]::14,:].copy()`

which does not work

`TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [[1, 3, 6, 8]] of <class 'list'>`

I got help with the code from here, which has been useful, but not on the multi-row selections -- 
[Pandas every nth row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055712/pandas-every-nth-row)

I can extract as several different slices and combine, but it feels like there may be a more elegant solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using:

```
df[np.isin(np.arange(len(df))%14,np.array([1,3,6,8]))]
```

Comment: Cheers, that does it nicely, and will absolutely be using that again in future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tuple comprehension with [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) and [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
arr = np.arange(14*3)
slices = tuple(slice(i, len(arr), 14) for i in (1, 3, 6, 8))

res = np.r_[slices]

print(res)

array([ 1, 15, 29,  3, 17, 31,  6, 20, 34,  8, 22, 36])
```

In this example, indexing dataframe rows with `1::14` is equivalent to indexing with `slice(1, df.shape[0], 14)`.

This is fairly generic, you can define any tuple of slice objects and pass to `np.r_`.

Comment: Thanks! This is neat for providing the indexes - used as `df.iloc[res,:]` works very nicely and the list comp is very pythonic. I dont know if it's as readable/elegant as Wen's answer though.

Comment: @DrBAC, For what it's worth, I think Wen's solution is better for your specific example. While my solution is more generic.