# How to Select value from column after every 5 rows and assign value to variable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am looking for an efficient and fast way to select a value: after 5 rows the 6th row value should be saved in variable X, and skip next 5 rows and take value 6th row and save in variable X.
Note: Every time remove previous value of x

```
data=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas every nth row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055712/pandas-every-nth-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can using `%`

```
s=pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17])
s[(np.arange(len(s))+1)%6==0].tolist()
[6, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data=pd.DataFrame(np.array([1,2,3,4,54,5,6,5,4,35,6,4,3,23,3]))
for i in data.iloc[::6][0]:
    X=i
```