# How can I skip even/odd rows while reading a csv file?

Tags: pandas, csv

Is there a simple way to ignore all even/odd rows when reading a csv using `pandas`?

I know `skiprows` argument in `pd.read_csv` but for that I'll need to know the number of rows in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas every nth row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055712/pandas-every-nth-row)

Comment: @Chris answer below was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pd.read_csv` `skiprows` argument accepts a callable, so you could use a lambda function.  E.g.:

```
df = pd.read_csv(some_path, skiprows=lambda x: x%2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution *after* reading would be:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(some_path)
# remove odd rows:
df = df.iloc[::2]
# remove even rows:
df = df.iloc[1::2]
```