# Python code to reads a csv file and print rows at even positions

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

- I have a CSV file.
- How do I read specific rows?
- I want to read the rows in the even positions?

```
import csv
with open('source.csv','rt')as f:
  data = csv.reader(f)
  for row in data:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free programming service. Show us the code you already have!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I skip even/odd rows while reading a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61087934/2745495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv('your_file')
dataframe_even_rows = dataframe.iloc[::2]
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
import csv

even_rows = []
# reading the csv
with open("file.csv", "r+") as csv_file:
    # reading all lines
    lines = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
    
    # extracting only even lines
    for i, line in zip(range(lines.line_num), lines):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            even_rows.append(line)

# printing output
for row in even_rows:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the solution provided by Adrien.

```
import pandas as pd
n = 1   #Number of rows you want to skip
dataframe = pd.read_csv('your_file')
dataframe_even_rows = dataframe.iloc[::(n+1)]
dataframe_specific_row = dataframe.iloc[2] #Specific lines: read third line(index start at 0)
```