# How to reduce a pandas Series by performing an operation on every set of N sequential elements

Tags: python, pandas, space-efficiency

Say I have a pandas series, and I want to take the mean of every set of 8 rows. I don't have prior knowledge of the size of the series, and the index may not be 0-based. I currently have the following

```py
N = 8

s = pd.Series(np.random.random(50 * N))

n_sets = s.shape[0] // N

split = ([m * N for m in range(n_sets)],
         [m * N for m in range(1, n_sets + 1)])

out_array = np.zeros(n_sets)

for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(*split)):

    out_array[i] = s.loc[s.index[a:b]].mean()
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `groupby`, by slicing the index in `N` (you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358895/13676202) an explanation of the slicing), and then use `pd.Series.mean()`:

```
newout_array=s.groupby(s.index//N).mean().to_list()
```

Output:

```
out_array  #original solution
[0.42147899 0.55668055 0.5222594  0.46066426 0.44378491 0.52719371
 0.42479113 0.46485387 0.2800083  0.57174865 0.59207811 0.58665479
 0.52414851 0.38158931 0.51884761 0.59007469 0.3449512  0.56385373
 0.34359674 0.44524997 0.44175351 0.42339394 0.5687501  0.3140091
 0.40985639 0.46649486 0.3101396  0.45664647 0.51829052 0.38875796
 0.45428001 0.52979064 0.62545921 0.64782618 0.65265239 0.56976799
 0.64277369 0.33528876 0.45973874 0.45341751 0.52690983 0.66427599
 0.59814577 0.35575622 0.62995929 0.61582329 0.38971679 0.4771326
 0.50889137 0.25105353]


newout_array  #new solution

[0.4214789945860148, 0.5566805507021909, 0.5222593998859411, 0.46066425607167216, 0.4437849132421554, 0.5271937114894408,
 0.424791134573943, 0.4648538659945887, 0.28000829556024387, 0.5717486453029332, 0.5920781058695997, 0.5866547941460012, 
 0.5241485100329547, 0.38158931177460725, 0.5188476113762392, 0.5900746905953183, 0.34495119855714756, 0.5638537286251522, 
 0.3435967359945349, 0.44524997190104454, 0.44175351484451975, 0.42339393886425913, 0.5687501027416468, 0.3140090963728155, 
 0.40985639015924036, 0.4664948621046134, 0.3101396034068746, 0.45664647332866076, 0.5182905157666298, 0.38875796468438406, 
 0.4542800111275337, 0.5297906368971982, 0.6254592119278896, 0.6478261817988752, 0.6526523935382951, 0.569767994485338, 
 0.642773691835847, 0.3352887578683835, 0.45973873832126594, 0.45341751320112617, 0.5269098312525405, 0.6642759923683706, 
 0.5981457683986061, 0.3557562229383897, 0.6299592930489117, 0.6158232897272005, 0.38971678834383916, 0.4771325988592886, 
 0.5088913710936904, 0.25105352820427246]
```

The difference it's because the number of decimals of each format, if you want to have only 8 decimals as the original `out_array`, you could try to `map` the elements with `round` function:

```
newout_array=s.groupby(s.index//N).mean().to_list()
newout_array=list(map(lambda x: round(x,8),newout_array))
```