# Update values with earlier date based on list by another dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to update the column `Value` of the dataframe `dateEANdf` with the values of the dataframe `valueEANdf` but only those rows with the earlier date.

An excerpt of `valueEANdf` looks as follows:

```
EAN-Unique  Value
3324324   3.0
asd2343   2.0
Xjkhfsd   1.2
5234XAR   4.5
3434343   2.6
```

An excerpt of `dateEANdf` looks as follows, it contains each EAN twice with an earlier and a later date.

```
EAN-Unique  Date         Start  Value 
3324324     2018-06-01   yes
3324324     2019-04-30   no
asd2343     2015-03-23   yes
asd2343     2015-07-11   no 
Xjkhfsd     1999-04-12   yes 
Xjkhfsd     2001-02-01   no 
5234XAR     2000-12-13   yes
5234XAR     2013-12-13   no
3434343     1972-05-23   yes   
3434343     1980-11-01   no
```

The updated `dateEANdf` should be as follows:

```
EAN-Unique  Date         Start  Value 
3324324     2018-06-01   yes    3.0
3324324     2019-04-30   no
asd2343     2015-03-23   yes    2.0
asd2343     2015-07-11   no 
Xjkhfsd     1999-04-12   yes    1.2
Xjkhfsd     2001-02-01   no 
5234XAR     2000-12-13   yes    4.5
5234XAR     2013-12-13   no
3434343     1972-05-23   yes    2.6
3434343     1980-11-01   no
```

My attempt was

```
dateEANdf.loc[ (dateEANdf['EAN-Unique'].isin(valueEANdf.unique().tolist())) & ( dateEANdf['Start'] == 'yes') , 'Value' ]  = valueEANdf['Value']
```

However, this puts the values "somewhere" like randomly but not to the earlier date. How to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `loc` slicing, then `map`:

```
s = dateEANdf['Start'].eq('yes')
dateEANdf.loc[s, 'Value'] = (dateEANdf.loc[s, 'EAN-Unique']
                                 .map(valueEANdf.set_index('EAN-Unique')['Value'])
                            )
```

Or map the whole series then `where`:

```
dateEANdf['Value'] = (dateEANdf['EAN-Unique'].map(valueEANdf.set_index('EAN-Unique')['Value'])
                          .where(dateEANdf['Start'].eq('yes'))
                     )
```

Output:

```
  EAN-Unique        Date Start  Value
0    3324324  2018-06-01   yes    3.0
1    3324324  2019-04-30    no    NaN
2    asd2343  2015-03-23   yes    2.0
3    asd2343  2015-07-11    no    NaN
4    Xjkhfsd  1999-04-12   yes    1.2
5    Xjkhfsd  2001-02-01    no    NaN
6    5234XAR  2000-12-13   yes    4.5
7    5234XAR  2013-12-13    no    NaN
8    3434343  1972-05-23   yes    2.6
9    3434343  1980-11-01    no    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do a `merge` and then update values with `np.where`:

```
# If 'Value' is not already in 'dateEANdf', then remove `dateEANdf.drop('Value', axis=1)`
dateEANdf = dateEANdf.drop('Value', axis=1).merge(valueEANdf, how='left', on='EAN-Unique')
dateEANdf['Value'] = np.where(dateEANdf['Start'] == 'no', np.nan, dateEANdf['Value'])
dateEANdf
Out[1]: 
  EAN-Unique        Date Start  Value
0    3324324  2018-06-01   yes    3.0
1    3324324  2019-04-30    no    NaN
2    asd2343  2015-03-23   yes    2.0
3    asd2343  2015-07-11    no    NaN
4    Xjkhfsd  1999-04-12   yes    1.2
5    Xjkhfsd  2001-02-01    no    NaN
6    5234XAR  2000-12-13   yes    4.5
7    5234XAR  2013-12-13    no    NaN
8    3434343  1972-05-23   yes    2.6
9    3434343  1980-11-01    no    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

---

You can also do:

```
dateEANdf['Value']=dateEANdf['EAN-Unique'].apply(
    lambda row: float(valueEANdf[valueEANdf['EAN-Unique']==row].Value))
```

which will give you:

```
  EAN-Unique          Date Start  Value
0    3324324    2018-06-01   yes    3.0
1    3324324    2019-04-30    no    3.0
2    asd2343    2015-03-23   yes    2.0
3    asd2343    2015-07-11    no    2.0
4    Xjkhfsd    1999-04-12   yes    1.2
5    Xjkhfsd    2001-02-01    no    1.2
6    5234XAR    2000-12-13   yes    4.5
7    5234XAR    2013-12-13    no    4.5
8    3434343    1972-05-23   yes    2.6
9    3434343    1980-11-01    no    2.6
```

Drop every second value in the value, relying on this thread: [Pandas every nth row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055712/pandas-every-nth-row):

```
dateEANdf.loc[1::2,'Value']=np.nan
```

which will result in:

```
  EAN-Unique          Date Start  Value
0    3324324    2018-06-01   yes    3.0
1    3324324    2019-04-30    no    NaN
2    asd2343    2015-03-23   yes    2.0
3    asd2343    2015-07-11    no    NaN
4    Xjkhfsd    1999-04-12   yes    1.2
5    Xjkhfsd    2001-02-01    no    NaN
6    5234XAR    2000-12-13   yes    4.5
7    5234XAR    2013-12-13    no    NaN
8    3434343    1972-05-23   yes    2.6
9    3434343    1980-11-01    no    NaN
```