# Keep all row with interval of 3 in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 
A    B    C
D    E    F
G    G    I
J    K    L
M    N    O
P    Q    R
S    T    U
V    W    X
Y    Z    A
```

and I would like to keep only intervals of 3 rows.
I should then get :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 
G    G    I
P    Q    R
Y    Z    A
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: `df.iloc[2::3]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas every nth row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055712/pandas-every-nth-row)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.iloc` and range:

```
df.iloc[range(2,len(df),3)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't a slicing do the job?:

```
df[2::3]
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`iloc` property](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) allows you to access slices of a dataframe similarly to a 2d numpy array, of a 1d list/tuple if slicing along the index (first axis).

In your case, as @QuangHoang answered:

```py
df.iloc[2::3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `groupby`

```
out = df.groupby(df.index//3).tail(1)
Out[446]: 
  COL1 COL2 COL3
2    G    G    I
5    P    Q    R
8    Y    Z    A
```