# How to sort a CSV file with Python to export every tenth row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using a CSV file with over 1,000,000 rows of data, however I need to export every 10th row into a new CSV.

The current CSV looks like this:

```
Date-Time   Weight(g)
26:07.1 -0.09
26:07.2 -0.09
26:07.3 -0.09
26:07.4 -0.09
26:07.5 -0.09
26:07.6 -0.09
26:07.7 -0.09
26:07.8 -0.09
26:07.9 81.05
26:07.9 81.02
26:08.0 80.98
26:08.1 81
```

Comment: Can you share what you tried ?

Comment: def logic(index):
    if index % 3 == 0:
       return True
    return False

I'm very new to Python but trying to learn for my job. I need to grab every 10th row and I have headers. TYIA

Comment: why 3 in you want 10th?

Comment: That's just the example I used from online. Would changing that to 10 give me every 10 rows? I need to import a CSV file, then filter out every 10th row, then put that into a CSV file and don't know how to export that into a CSV either

Answer (score 0):

You can slice your dataframe and then export it:

```py
df.iloc[::10, :].to_csv(filepath)
```

See also this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055712/pandas-every-nth-row)