# Python polars: modify every nth row

Tags: python, indexing, slice, python-polars

Given a polars DataFrame in Python, how can I modify every nth element in a series?

```py
# have
df = pl.DataFrame(pl.Series("a", [1, -1, 1, -1, 1]))
# want
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

# selecting works fine:
df["a", 1::2]
shape: (2,)
Series: 'a' [i64]
[
    -1
    -1
]

# but modification fails:
df["a", 1::2] *= -1
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_103522/957012809.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    df["a", 1::2] *= -1

  File "/home/.../.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py", line 1439, in __setitem__
    raise ValueError(f"column selection not understood: {col_selection}")

ValueError: column selection not understood: slice(1, None, 2)
```

```
pl.__version__
'0.15.14'
```

[pandas version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25055712/10197418)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add in the row count and use the modulo operator:

```
df.with_row_count().select(
   pl.when((pl.col("row_nr") + 1) % 2 == 0)
     .then(pl.col("a") * -1)
     .otherwise(pl.col("a"))
)
```

```
shape: (5, 1)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 1   │
├─────┤
│ 1   │
├─────┤
│ 1   │
├─────┤
│ 1   │
├─────┤
│ 1   │
└─────┘
```